# Darknet demo needs opencv for webcam images OpenCV=1

Tags: object-detection, yolo, darknet

I have been doing object detection with Yolo with the darknet git repository and wanted to start with video, I instaled OpenCV and try to run darknet for videos as:

```
$ ./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights <video file>
```

but I have the following message:

```
$ demo needs opencv for webcam images
```

I changed the second line in the makefile to:

```
 OpenCV=1
```

but the message continue showing, and in the forums only. I followed a tutorial (https://pjreddie.com/darknet/install/#cuda), but I do not not what re-make the project is and the test at the end shows that it is not compiling with opencv. I tried to remake it with:

```
remake darknet
```

but I have the following error with the libraries:

```
include/darknet.h:11:30: fatal error: cuda_runtime.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Edit: I think is the instalation of CUDA as the comand nvidia-smi does not anything

Comment: try to have a clean installation of cuda toolkit first.

Comment: I needed to "rebuild" darknet after I changed the Makefile to have OpenCV=1 using cmake-gui. I had to set the OpenCV_DIR variable of CMakeCache.txt to my opencv build library which was in my Anaconda environment: {path to user}\.conda\envs\tf_gpu\Library\lib. As a result, cmake-gui says OpenCV has been found so I used VS2019 to build the project and tried accessing the webcam again with darknet. Same error. I thought darknet with OpenCV found would solve it but... :(